# Same question as another user, answer didn't work for me

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

What is the best way to add a question to an existing question?

That is, a question was asked and answered, but the solution either didn't address the whole issue, or didn't work for me.

Comment: Ask a new question, describe the problem, reference the old question and describe why it didn't work for you. Voilà! A new, unique question!

Comment: `[duplicate]` ah, the irony.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best way to add a question to an existing question?

Don't.
You may have the exact same problem that is already covered by an existing question, but you shouldn't add to that question or try to engage in extended conversation via the comments.

What you should do is post your own version of the question, and make sure you include a reference to the original question with an explanation of why it isn't a duplicate or suitable to you.

Alternatively if you have enough reputation you can post a bounty on the original question (even though it's not yours) as a way of attracting new answers. Part of the bounty process is detailing the reason why you are posting the bounty - you can explain there that you have the same problem but the existing answer(s) don't work for you.